# Open Source Historical Weather Data API

Tags: data, arcgis-web-appbuilder, weather

My client requires weather data for an application that has wind speed, wind direction aggregated by zip code for individual days of the week.  Where can this be acquired to be used in an Esri Web Mapping Application?  I have the capabilities to integrate this for a custom widget solution.

Comment: For open data I think you should consider researching/asking at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: like http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q=London,UK&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the NOAA page. It contains numerous open source datasets over varying intervals. https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/datasets

Answer (score 0):

https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/request/download.phtml?network=MN_ASOS is my favorite. We used it extensively for aviation purposes.

As a general rule, it can be assumed that airport weather stations are reasonably well sited, and are in a reasonable state of repair and calibration.